# Cannot Get iOS app Interface to Load to test my app

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

Good Day All.  I am taking a course on Udemy. I am having trouble getting an app called "Dicee" to work for me. This following narrated screencast shows the results that I am getting.

This following narrated screencast shows the results that I am getting. My code seems to match the instrcutor's exactly from the lesson, but I am getting a very different error.  The interface will not even load to press the roll button to test the random command.

[PLEASE WATCH SCREENCAST HERE](https://www.hippovideo.io/video/play/P2FUyEq1qtdEKOWD-xbAdD7FdnUtecZ7GnlzKQ-sorI)

Specs for the Mac that I am using is as follows:

Using Xcode version: Version 10.1 (10B61)
Macbook Pro specs: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)
Processor: 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7
Memory: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB
Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

If someone could please look this over and let me know what I have missed, that would be great.  Thank You!

Comment: Hey Michael, I have seen your video and it seems like one possible way of solving this is to us actually have access to the Xcode project. If you don't mind uploading your project somewhere in the internet would work best. Or contact me via https://www.patreon.com/excitedmicrobe , this is what i do and i'll be happy to have a look over project with teamviewer anytime today

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem after upgrading to Xcode10 (or 10.1 in your case).
I would guess that although everything is the same in your code compared to the teachers, their version of Xcode is different.

If you switch the simulator to a newer model (like iPhone XS) then your problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any error found in designing you just have to add constraint to relevant. and then you need to check the outlets which may be conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your storyboard and add constraints to the elements. To add constraints, you need to click on a little icon at the bottom of the storyboard view. Set the green background to center horizontally and vertically and then add other constraints for the other elements and make sure the z position for the other elements is higher than the background so they don't get hidden.